# Animate an expanding drawing in iOS UIView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, calayer

I would like to create a custom dynamic drawing inside a UIView using a CGContext so that when I execute a UIView animation on it the drawing will be rendered during animation/interpolation.  I tried using a custom CALayer and override its draw method but that fails.  I tried subclassing a UIView draw(_ in:CGRect) but that gets drawn only first time.  This is what I want to do:

```
class RadioWaveView : UIView {
    override func draw(_ in:CGRect) {
        // draw something, for example an ellipse based on frame size, something like this:
        // let context = CGGraphicsCurrentContext()
        // context.addEllipse(self.frame)
        // Unfortunately this method is called only once, not during animation
    }
}
```

in `viewDidAppear()`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 1, options: [.repeat], animations: {
        self.myRadioWaveView.frame = CGRect(x:100,y:100,width:200,heigh:300)
    }, completion: { flag in
    })
```

The animation works because I set the background color of `myRadioWaveView` and see it expand on screen.  Placing a breakpoint in `draw` shows that it is executed only once.

EDIT: In essence, I am asking this question: How can we create a custom UIView and use UIView.animate() to animate that view's rendering?  Let's keep the UIView.animate() method, and how can we animate an expanding circle (or any other custom drawing within a UIView) ?

EDIT: Here is a custom class I created to draw just a triangle.  When I animate its bounds, the triangle scales with the underlying image of the view but the draw method is not called during the animation.  I don't want that; I want the draw() method to redraw the drawing every frame of the animation.

```
open class TriangleView : UIView {

override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width,y:0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/2,y:self.frame.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint.zero)
    path.closeSubpath()
    context.beginPath()
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(3)
    context.addPath(path)
    context.closePath()
    context.strokePath()
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simplest way

## Full example code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var animatableView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Circle
        //animatableView.layer.cornerRadius = animatableView.bounds.size.height/2
        //animatableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        //triangle
        self.applyTriangle(givenView: animatableView)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 1, options: [.repeat], animations: {
            self.animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
        }) { (finished) in
            self.animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
        
    }
    
    func applyTriangle(givenView: UIView){
        
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: givenView.bounds.width / 2, y: givenView.bounds.width))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: givenView.bounds.width, y: 0))
        bezierPath.close()
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: givenView.layer)
        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.frame = givenView.bounds
        shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true
        givenView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**Results**

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Perhaps I should have tried to draw a triangle -- could you change your answer to animate an expanding triangle?  In reality I am trying to animate a custom drawing, circle was just an example.

Comment: For triangle must work as the same, you only have to custom draw a triangle in your UIView and it must work, if don't work let me know ok?

Comment: How would you encode drawing a triangle in your example?  I tried overriding the draw() method but that doesn't work.

Comment: @andrewz take a look

Comment: I understand what you did -- this looks EXACTLY how I want it to look.  This is however different from how I understand the solution should work.  The drawing is not recreated, it is redrawn, but that's fine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

I had been working in your question, this approach is using Using `CABasicAnimation` and `CAShapeLayer` I had defined a custom `UIView` Class to make the work, I will add further improvements `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectables`

```
import UIKit

class RadioWaveAnimationView: UIView {

    var animatableLayer : CAShapeLayer?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height/2

        self.animatableLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        self.animatableLayer?.fillColor = self.backgroundColor?.cgColor
        self.animatableLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        self.animatableLayer?.frame = self.bounds
        self.animatableLayer?.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height/2
        self.animatableLayer?.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.animatableLayer!)
        self.startAnimation()
    }


    func startAnimation()
    {
        let layerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        layerAnimation.fromValue = 1
        layerAnimation.toValue = 3
        layerAnimation.isAdditive = false

        let layerAnimation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        layerAnimation2.fromValue = 1
        layerAnimation2.toValue = 0
        layerAnimation2.isAdditive = false

        let groupAnimation = CAAnimationGroup()
        groupAnimation.animations = [layerAnimation,layerAnimation2]
        groupAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(2)
        groupAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        groupAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        groupAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity

        self.animatableLayer?.add(groupAnimation, forKey: "growingAnimation")
    }
    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}
```

***Results***

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: This is an alternative answer.  Would you know why in my original question the oberriden draw() method is not called during UIView animate()?

Comment: I appreciate the hard work you put into this answer, but this is not the answer I am looking for -- it should not be so difficult to animate an expanding circle.  There must be an easier solution that uses the UIView.animate() static method.

Answer (score 2):

Two answers in one.. First, if you really want `drawRect` to be called on every pass, you should use a `CADisplayLink` and manually animate the frame of the view.
Second: If you don't want to do that but still want it to draw smoothly, then set the contentMode to scaleAspectFit. This will make it draw smoothly with `UIView.animateWithDuration`. However, it will NOT call `drawRect` every cycle where-as the `CADisplayLink` solution does.

Use a `CADisplayLink` that updates the bounds every frame. Add `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true` so that the view will redraw whenever the bounds are changed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv1sE.gif

[image]

Example:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  StackOverflow
//
//  Created by Brandon T on 2017-07-22.
//  Copyright © 2017 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class RadioWave : UIView {

    private var dl: CADisplayLink?
    private var startTime: CFTimeInterval!
    private var fromFrame: CGRect!
    private var toFrame: CGRect!
    private var duration: CFTimeInterval!
    private var completion: (() -> Void)?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.isOpaque = false
        self.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true;
        self.fromFrame = frame;
        self.toFrame = frame
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func animateToFrame(frame: CGRect, duration: CFTimeInterval, completion:(() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.dl?.remove(from: .current, forMode: .commonModes)
        self.dl?.invalidate()
        self.dl = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(onUpdate(dl:)))

        self.completion = completion
        self.fromFrame = self.frame
        self.toFrame = frame
        self.duration = duration
        self.startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        self.dl?.add(to: .current, forMode: .commonModes)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        ctx?.clear(rect)

        ctx?.addEllipse(in: rect)
        ctx?.clip()
        ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        ctx?.fill(rect)
    }

    @objc
    func onUpdate(dl: CADisplayLink) {
        let dt = CGFloat((dl.timestamp - self.startTime) / self.duration)

        if (dt > 1.0) {
            self.frame = self.toFrame
            self.dl?.remove(from: .current, forMode: .commonModes)
            self.dl?.invalidate()
            self.dl = nil

            completion?()
            completion = nil
            return;
        }

        var frame: CGRect! = self.toFrame;
        frame.origin.x = (self.toFrame.origin.x - self.fromFrame.origin.x) * dt + fromFrame.origin.x
        frame.origin.y = (self.toFrame.origin.y - self.fromFrame.origin.y) * dt + fromFrame.origin.y
        frame.size.width = (self.toFrame.size.width - self.fromFrame.size.width) * dt + fromFrame.size.width
        frame.size.height = (self.toFrame.size.height - self.fromFrame.size.height) * dt + fromFrame.size.height
        self.frame = frame
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var radioWave: RadioWave!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.radioWave = RadioWave(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 10.0, y: self.view.center.y - 10.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0))

        self.view.addSubview(self.radioWave)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            let smallFrame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 10.0, y: self.view.center.y - 10.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
            let largeFrame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 100.0, y: self.view.center.y - 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0)

            self.radioWave.animateToFrame(frame: largeFrame, duration: 2.0, completion: {

                self.radioWave.animateToFrame(frame: smallFrame, duration: 2.0)

                })
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Views are usually only redrawn when their bounds change. An animation on iOS is actually just a snapshot of your view being interpolated (Presentation Layer). This give a huge performance boost rather than redrawing and laying out the view on every animation step.

Animating a circle with `[UIView animateWithDuration]`

```
class RadioWave : UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.isOpaque = false
        self.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
        self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        ctx?.clear(rect)

        ctx?.addEllipse(in: rect)
        ctx?.clip()
        ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        ctx?.fill(rect)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var radioWave: RadioWave!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.radioWave = RadioWave(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 10.0, y: self.view.center.y - 10.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0))

        self.view.addSubview(self.radioWave)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            let largeFrame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 100.0, y: self.view.center.y - 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0)

            self.radioWave.setNeedsDisplay()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.layoutSubviews, .autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {

                self.radioWave.frame = largeFrame
            }, completion: { (completed) in

            })
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

The above uses the contentMode `scaleAspectFit` which allows the animation to scale properly without blurring! This is the only way that I know of, to draw smooth circles while it animates. It will NOT call drawRect until the beginning and end of each animation.

Comment: I appreciate the hard work you put into this answer, but this is not the answer I am looking for -- it should not be so difficult to animate an expanding circle.  There must be an easier solution that uses the UIView.animate() static method.

Comment: @andrewz; I added code that uses `UIView.animateWIthDuration` I fixed the blurring issue by setting the contentMode.

Comment: Yes, I wanted draw() to be called on every frame ... now I realize that using CADisplayLink is the only way to achieve that.  What I didn't realize is the way UIKit works during animations is that it tries to optimize by not recreating the drawing every frame, but by performing transformations on the already composed image and redrawing dynamic drawings like bezier curves.  I guess recreating a drawing would require reallocating an image and that would be costly.